# Числа, входящие как множители в факториал

Tags: pascal

Как вывести на экран все числа, которые перемножаются при подсчёте факториала?

> Дано произвольное натуральное число N. Напечатать все цифры десятичной записи числа N!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Варианта 2:

- Объявить переменную-аккумулятор равную 1, сделать цикл по переменной i от 1 до N, и в цикле домножать аккумулятор на текущее значение i.
- Рекурсивно вызывать функцию f(x), возвращающую x*f(x-1), пока x больше ноля.